# jQuery .appendTo with a variable and text

Tags: jquery

I have a variable that I would like to append added to some other text.
My first though was this:

```
var wood  = 5
$(wood+"<p>bits of wood left</p>" ).appendTo("#notifications");
```

Then I tried this:

```
var wood  = 5
var woodLeft=(wood + "wood left");
$(woodLeft).appendTo("#notifications");
```

But that doesn't work either. Any ideas of how to get this to function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is jQuery thinks you're passing a selector to it, and then throws an error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 5<p>bits of wood left</p>`
Solution: Tell jQuery to explicitly parse it as html.

```
var wood  = 5
$($.parseHTML(wood+"<p>bits of wood left</p>" )).appendTo("#notifications");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rg7trxov/

Comment: Thanks, that really helped out!
How would I go about getting the number on the same line?

Comment: By not using a block level tag like a `p`, you can use a `span` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
$("#notifications").append(wood+"<p>bits of wood left</p>" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3f1vq72/

Comment: .. and for markups' sake I would put `wood` inside the `<p>`

Comment: Eric Mahieu
How would I do that?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do... but you can say `"<p>bits of wood"+wood.toString()+"</p>"`.